# Програмно перезагрузить Android

Tags: android, java

Возможно ли программно перезагрузить устройство с Android OS без root? Найденный на англоязычном ресурсе код не работает:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  
pm.reboot("null")
```

Соответствующее разрешение в манифесте было добавлено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перезагрузка не может осуществляться обычным приложением, собранным с помощью обычного SDK. Только приложения, подписанные системным ключом, могут запрашивать перезагрузку. Системные ключи обычно расположены здесь:

```
<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security
```

Вы можете использовать их для подписи своего приложения, тогда приведенный вами код будет работать.

Comment: чего??? вы совершенно не правы

Answer (score 2):

Собственно перезагрузка осуществляется через `PowerManager.reboot()`. Требуется разрешение в манифесте [REBOOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT)

Подпись как указано у [@Привет](/users/4296/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) - естественно требуется.

Answer (score 0):

В рантайме

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("system/bin/su").write("reboot").getBytes();
```